# Heroku app - log folder

Tags: python, logging, heroku, flask

As [Heroku has read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) except two directories (log and tmp) I wanted to dump my logs from python app to one of them.

The git repository pushed to heroku server app contains both of the folders created by my (checked twice, even downloaded app after push to check if both dirs are there).
While running "heroku run bash" I am able to see only the "tmp" folder - "log" is not visible using "ls -la" or even to the app as I receive errors regarding missing location for the .log files.

```
2013-08-05T13:10:41.170434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python runserver.py`
2013-08-05T13:10:43.132418+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-08-05T13:10:43.609980+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
2013-08-05T13:10:43.725134+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app_name import app
2013-08-05T13:10:43.850738+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app_name/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
2013-08-05T13:10:43.968714+00:00 app[web.1]:     from logger import flask_debug
2013-08-05T13:10:44.081900+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/logger.py", line 8, in <module>
2013-08-05T13:10:44.194540+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging.config.dictConfig(CONFIG)
2013-08-05T13:10:44.306174+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 797, in dictConfig
2013-08-05T13:10:44.425589+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2013-08-05T13:10:44.535392+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 579, in configure
2013-08-05T13:10:44.274067+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-05T13:10:44.287252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

So quick thinking I wanted to check if I can place the logs in tmp folder. The app starts, everything looks fine... but nothing is dumped from the app.

I am lost actually as I've looked for the solution quite a time.

Maybe someone will tell me:

1. Why "log" directory under /app_name folder is not visible?
2. Why "tmp" directory is not receiving logs?

   http://speedy.sh/VaR2w/logger.conf - here's the *.conf file for my loggers
   http://speedy.sh/c3QNs/logger.py - here are loggers

PS. Logs are working for the console for the "tmp" folder configuration.

Comment: I usually hate this kind of comments, but: can you share what exactly you are trying to achieve by writing logs to disk? The logs will "disappear" any time the dyno boots (about once daily), plus if you have several dynos they will write different logs, if you manually restart a dyno, etc... If you want to persist logs from your app for your own use there are better ways.

Comment: I kind of worried that this might be the answer, as heroku works as you responded.

Although I am still curious why I cannot see /log while it was written that I should have the access to it and why, even if the app was not restarted, there are no logs in /tmp.

What better ways do you have in mind? :)

Answer (score 0):

Two better ways:

1) Using Heroku's logdrain feature: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog-drains

2) Using one of the addons: *Papertrail* and *Logly* come to mind, both have free plans.

I use #1 above: I have an ec2 instance I set up that aggregates all the logs from all of my dynos into a specific set of files, which I use `logrotate` to manage. I then use simple `grep` to search thru them, and `tail -f` to follow, if I feel like it. My rsyslogd configuration on said ec2 instance is:

----- 8< ----- cut here ----- 8< ----- cut here ----- 8< ----- cut here -----
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 5514

```
# vi /etc/rsyslog.d/01-heroku.conf
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[postgres]' then /matchspot-logs/postgres
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[pgbackups]' then /matchspot-logs/postgres
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'heroku[' then /matchspot-logs/heroku
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[' then /matchspot-logs/app
& ~
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have a credit card, and without verification Heroku won't let me add anything even if it's free.
Although thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: Are you sure? Not even log drains? Absolutely sure?

Comment: I could not turn on the redis, and I just tried loggly as well.
The thing is that even if using basic addon is free, it won't be turned on without account verification - only possible by credit card :(

Comment: Re-read what I suggested: use *log drains* (option 1 in my answer). It's not an add on, and you can direct your logs to a micro ec2 instance, which is free.

Answer (score 0):

when you `heroku run`, it spins up a new dyno so as not to degrade your web server's performance... think about it like this, if you had 2 web dynos, which one would you get when you `heroku run`? :)

the approaches suggested by other people here should work way better for you

also, you *should* be able to add free addons without a confirmed account